# extracting individual element from pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have saved the following panda file into CSV now how do I get it back as a panda file(dataframe) in another program.And is it possible to get single element from the dataframe like for example I want the element of 10th row 3rd column specifically like how it can be done in numpy

```
   df = af.merge(df, on='DateTime', how='left').interpolate()
   print(df)
   df.to_csv("my_csvfilename.csv")
```

I get the output

```
         DateTime            pop
    0    2011-01-01  627000.000000
    1    2011-01-02  627024.657534
    2    2011-01-03  627049.315068
    3    2011-01-04  627073.972603
    4    2011-01-05  627098.630137
    ...         ...            ...
    3648 2020-12-27  713000.000000
    3649 2020-12-28  713000.000000
    3650 2020-12-29  713000.000000
    3651 2020-12-30  713000.000000
    3652 2020-12-31  713000.000000
```

Comment: `df.iloc[10,3]`

Comment: is there a way to get the dataframe exactly as it is from the saved CSV file, like when I want it in another program?

Comment: @Reza `df.iloc[9,2]`

Comment: if your other program is python use `to_pickle()` instead of `to_csv()` to more simply maintain all data type and other information.  CSV is a very crude interchange mechanism

Comment: Agree with Rob Raymond but depends what you want to do. If you want to read the file in Excel or something, then pickle wont work and csv might be the better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have suggested how to extract specific elements above but retrieving the file in the first place should be as simple as

```
  import pandas as pd
  df=pd.read_csv("my_csvfilename.csv")
```

If you aren't in the same directory you may need to amend to be

```
  df=pd.read_csv(r"C:\directory\my_csvfilename.csv")
```

But obviously you need the correct path to the directory (e.g. C:\My folder\My subfolder)